# How to limit client connection in OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-12.04

How can I limit a client maximum connection in OpenVPN? What I really want is to restrict more than one device using one client account? How can I do that? Is it even possible? I've seen in OpenVPN Access Server such thing.

Comment: Do you use directive `duplicate-cn` in your `server.conf` ? If yes, comment it out and you should not be able to have more than one connexion for a given client account.

Comment: @user2196728 It's something like this: `;duplicate-cn` Is it enable or I should comment it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to

1. Generate a new cert for each client
2. NOT use the duplicate-cn directive

If you do this, then a client can't ever have more than one session at the same time.

Comment: I know I generate new cert for each client but what is difference between `;duplicate-cn` and `duplicate-cn`?

Comment: The first one with the ";" means that duplicate-cn is turned off.  The other means that it's turned on.  The ";" is a comment character, meaning ignore the line in the file.

Comment: But in my server config file it was commented like first one but stil one user can connect with multiple devices!

Comment: Is the same cert used on all the devices, at the same time?

Comment: Yes same cert could connect multiple devices!

Comment: You may need to make sure that duplicate-cn is commented out in the server config, and then restart the openvpn server.  If the problem continues -- that's really weird.  With my installation it will kick off previous connections for the same client.

Comment: No the problem still continues and it also weird for me. I edited `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` and changed it to `;duplicate-cn`, `duplicate-cn`, and `# ;duplicate-cn` and restarted server from `/etc/init.d/openvpn ! Which part is wrong?  I tested three ways but all of them have same result: connecting multiple clients!

Comment: But is the problem from devices? I used same cert for OpenVPN Connect android and my laptop by using OpenVPN Client for testing . Is the problem related them?